# Recieving error when updating with subquery within SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've run into an error where my subquery returns more values than the permitted "1".

I'm trying to update Table [I] with the.QUERY value from Table [P].

Both tables are from different databases. They have the same value in column ID.
And I want to try out ID's 100-150 as a test first.

```
UPDATE I 
    SET I.metadata02 = (SELECT CAST([XML]AS xml)
                            .query(N'/inkoopfacturen/inkoopfactuur/jaar')
                            .value('.', 'varchar(30)') 
                    FROM [Archive190404132717].[dbo].[tblArchiveInvoices])    
FROM tblindex AS I 
    INNER JOIN [Archive190404132717].[dbo].[tblArchiveInvoices] AS P 
        ON  I.ID = P.ID    
WHERE 
    I.tasknumber BETWEEN '100' and '150'
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983). Clearly your subquery returns more than 1 row, so what are you expecting here? You can't update a single row with the value of many rows, so what are you after?

Comment: Hey Larnu, im trying to update several rows (id's 100-150) with the value coming from the cast, and the ID's matching in both tables.

Comment: But your sub query returns many rows. If your subquery returns the **rows** `1`,`2`,`3` and `4`, what would you expect the column's (`metadata02`)  value set to? Your comment doesn't answer my question

Comment: My subquery needs to select one value from the table. It has to match the I.ID on P.ID. But i dont know how to get my subquery to match the ID's.

Comment: People have to be able to read the query before they can help. That subquery is trying to extract data from *all* rows of `tblArchiveInvoices`, not just the joined row

Comment: is there a trigger on tblindex?

Comment: `My subquery needs to select one value from the table.` on the contrary, that subquery returns *all* table rows. You should use the P.xml field directly, eg `SET ... = cast(P.XML as XML).query(...)`

Comment: Im trying "set I.metadata02 = cast(p.XML as xml).query(N'/inkoopfacturen/inkoopfactuur/jaar').value('.', 'varchar(30)')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, seems like what you are actually after is actually just this:

```
UPDATE I
SET I.metadata02 = CAST([XML] AS xml).query(N'/inkoopfacturen/inkoopfactuur/jaar').value('.', 'varchar(30)')
FROM tblindex I
     INNER JOIN [Archive190404132717].[dbo].[tblArchiveInvoices] P ON I.ID = P.ID
WHERE I.tasknumber BETWEEN '100' AND '150';
```

There's no need for the subquery, and the 2nd reference to `tblArchiveInvoices`; you've already joined to it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using both a subquery *and* `join`?  I assume you want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE I 
    SET I.metadata02 = (SELECT CAST([XML]AS xml)
                               .query(N'/inkoopfacturen/inkoopfactuur/jaar')
                               .value('.', 'varchar(30)') 
                        FROM [Archive190404132717].[dbo].[tblArchiveInvoices]
                        WHERE I.ID = P.ID  
                       )
FROM tblindex I 
WHERE I.tasknumber BETWEEN '100' and '150';
```

Also, a field called `tasknumber` should really be stored as a number.  The comparison as strings can be misleading.  If it is a number, drop the single quotes.  If it is a string, you should realize that `'10001` meets the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Im dropping the quotes. Tasknumber is indeed a number.
Using "set I.metadata02 = cast(p.XML as xml).query(N'/inkoopfacturen/inkoopfactuur/jaar').value('.', 'varchar(30)')" Solved the problem for me.

Comment: @KoenSchutte . . . Either method works.  It seemed like a smaller change to your query to keep the subquery and remove the `join`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're trying something like this:

```
UPDATE I 
SET metadata02 = X
FROM tblindex AS I 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, CAST([XML]AS xml).query(N'/inkoopfacturen/inkoopfactuur/jaar').value('.', 'varchar(30)') AS X
            FROM [Archive190404132717].[dbo].[tblArchiveInvoices] ) AS P 
            ON  I.ID = P.ID    
WHERE I.tasknumber BETWEEN '100' and '150'
```